# how to retrieve latest data from django model in tamplates

Tags: django, django-views

i am trying to retrieve latest single data from Django model and show it in templates instead of all the data the method I trying to use in my view to achieve that

```
def preview(request):
    readme = Personal_readme.objects.latest('create_date')
    return render(request, 'preview.html',{'readme':readme})
```

and in my models

```
create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
```

but when I runserve and refer to a page it
TypeError at /preview/
Personal_readme' object is not iterable
it work fine when use this

```
readme = Personal_readme.objects.all()
```

but retrieve all the data in it but i want to retrieve single(one) the latest data based on create_date

I have no idea why its is show like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your template waits list of items, and when you give it one, it cause to error.
So you can change your template to handle 1 item, or give it `list` with 1 item like so:

```
def preview(request):
    readme = [Personal_readme.objects.latest('create_date')]
    return render(request, 'preview.html',{'readme': readme})
```